# Проблема с переменными при добавлении

Tags: php

Подскажите, почему не находит мои переменные. Интерпретатор PHP выдает:

> Undefined index: name

и т.д. Так на все переменные.

```
function get_add_item_form() 
{ 
  echo '<h2>Добавить</h2>';  
  echo '<form name="addform" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=add" method="post">'; 
  echo '<table>'; 
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>номер</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="number" value="" /></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>имя</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="name" value="" /></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>сообщение</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="message" value="" /></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>дата</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="date" value="" /></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td></td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="submit" value="Сохранить"></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
  echo '</table>'; 
  echo '</form>'; 
}

// Функция добавляет новую запись в таблицу БД  
function add_item() 
{ 
  $number = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['number'] ); 
  $name = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['name'] ); 
  $message = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['message'] ); 
  $date = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['date'] ); 
  $query = "INSERT INTO call_cons (number, name,message,data) VALUES ('".$number."', '".$name."', '".$message."', '".$date."');"; 
  mysql_query ( $query ); 
  header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
  die();
}
```

Comment: попробуйте продампить `$_POST`  `var_dump($_POST)` сразу увидите, почему так

Comment: Функции `mysql_` устарели, их использовать **нельзя**!

Comment: после дампа выводит нормально переменные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суперглобальный массив `$_POST` содержит данные передаваемые в POST запросе. В вашем случае, интерпретатор PHP выдает:

> Undefined index: name

что означает, что POST запрос не содержит переменной с именем `name`. Почему ее там нет, это уже другой вопрос.

Посмотреть содержимое массива `$_POST` можно, например, вот так:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение,не подскажите как исправить это?

Comment: @zkolya, для начала вам нужно понять _почему_ там этой переменной нет. Могу предположить, что вы обращаетесь к скрипту напрямую, вместо отправки ему формы. Но это только догадка.